Interpreting Arithmetic
In the context of 0-1 law. I saw some papers by Shelah and others in which they claim that in order to show that 0-1 law fails in a theory, it is enough to interpret arithmetic in it. It is not clear to me, what it exactly means. I asked some people to explain it to me and they referred me to Spencer's book, "the strange logic of random graphs". I looked at the book and tried to understand it, but unfortunately I could not. Because it is vague in my opinion. That still looks like a blackbox for me. In general, I guess, I know what interpretation means. What I do not really understand how they interpret arithmetic. Is there anyone who may explain it?
See this paper:
Shelah, S., & Spencer, J. (1988). Zero-One Laws for Sparse Random Graphs. Journal of the American Mathematical Society, 1(1), 97–115. https://doi.org/10.2307/1990968

It would be helpful for you to provide a specific reference to one of the papers that is making the claim that is giving you problems. This will clarify exactly what is meant by "0-1 law fails in a theory", which is not obvious without more context.

@RobArthan For example: Zero-One Laws for Sparse Random Graphs,
By: Saharon Shelah and Joel Spencer,
Journal of the American Mathematical Society

Please don't clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your post so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time and is useful to others.
